# Insert array into MySQL database with PHP and JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I want insert following date values as json value in database mysql, as following example:

I want they as in database table row:

```
     Column static  |                     Column data_1
Row1:      12       |  ["1111111111", "2222222222", "3333333333", "4444444444"]
Row2:      34       |  ["5555555555", "6666666666", "7777777777"]
Row1:      56       |  ["8888888888", "9999999999"]
```

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/WzGz3p

```
<form method="post">
<input name="static[]" value="12">
<input name="data_1[]" value="1111111111">
<input name="data_1[]" value="2222222222">
<input name="data_1[]" value="3333333333">
<input name="data_1[]" value="4444444444">

<input name="static[]" value="34">
<input name="data_1[]" value="5555555555">
<input name="data_1[]" value="6666666666">
<input name="data_1[]" value="7777777777">

<input name="static[]" value="56">
<input name="data_1[]" value="8888888888">
<input name="data_1[]" value="9999999999">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

My php code that don't work true:

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data_1 = $_POST['data_1'];
$static = $_POST["static"];
foreach($static as $idx=>$val){
    $data[] = array(
              'static' => $static[$idx],
              'data_1' => json_encode(Array($data_1[$idx*2],$data_1[$idx*2+1]))             
                   );
}
//$this->db->insert_batch('MyTable', $data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: What is NOT working? Can you tell us any error that is occurring or any similar symptoms? `My php code that don't work true:` doesn't make people understand your problem adequately

Comment: Are you sure you want the dates serialized in one column? Sounds like a database design issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this format data to store it in a database, but if you want to save in this way you must do a few changes:

Change your form:

you are working with non fixed number of fields, you can use an structure like:

```
<input name="static[NUMBER]" value="XXX">
<input name="data_NUMBER[1]" value="YYYYY">
```

and in php you can get the info of the `static=NUMBER` as `$_POST["data_".NUMBER]`

```
<form method="post">
<input name="static[1]" value="12">
<input name="data_1[0]" value="1111111111">
<input name="data_1[1]" value="2222222222">
<input name="data_1[2]" value="3333333333">
<input name="data_1[3]" value="4444444444">

<input name="static[2]" value="34">
<input name="data_2[0]" value="5555555555">
<input name="data_2[1]" value="6666666666">
<input name="data_2[2]" value="7777777777">

<input name="static[3]" value="56">
<input name="data_3[0]" value="8888888888">
<input name="data_3[1]" value="9999999999">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and change the php:

```
foreach($static as $idx=>$val){
    $data_=$_POST["data_".$idx];
    $data[] = array(
        'static' => $static[$idx],
        'data_1' => json_encode($data_)             
    );
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/i2xvKC (demo here)